# How the map of cosmic microwave background is being made?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

[image]
I wonder

- Where are we in this picture?
- How this picture is being made? does this have a similarity with world map, if so, we know world map is depicting a 2 dimensional space, how the map of CMB contain the information of a 3 dimensional space?

Comment: We are no where on this map. This map shows the "temperature" of the CMB photons coming from all directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that map is an unfolded image of the whole sky, squashed flat onto a 2-D rendering. imagine that map is printed on a sheet of rubber. Now imagine gluing that sheet to the inside of a hollow sphere. Stretch the rubber map to fit. now sit at the center of that sphere and look around.

The CMB radiation which is in that map comes to us from so very far away that it does not matter which parts of it might be a little closer to us and which parts are a little farther away; it can be accurately portrayed in 2-D map sheet, which represents all of space as described above.